# How to replace a ConditionalOnMissingBean bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I use a library which contains

```
public class MyFilter extends FilterParent { ... }
```

and

```
@Configuration
public class AutoConf
{
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(FilterParent.class)
    public MyFilter myFilter ()
    {
        return new MyFilter (); //               <------- I want to replace this
    }
}
```

which loads correctly. I cannot change this library but I want to load a different filter bean

I tried

```
@Component
public class MyNewFilter extends MyFilter { ... }
```

and modified the application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run (Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner (ApplicationContext ctx)
    {
        return args -> {
            // startup code
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public MyFilter myFilter ()
    {
        return new MyNewFilter (); //          <----------- THIS IS NEW
    }
}
```

But I still get `MyFilter` loaded instead of a `MyNewFilter`.

How can I load a `MyNewFilter` bean instead of the `MyFilter` bean loaded by `AutoConf`, without changing `AutoConf`?

Comment: This should work fine. Start by inspecting the auto-configuration report you get with `--debug`.

Comment: How you got to know that your new Bean is not being used. As pointed by @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    SpringApplication.run (Application.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner (ApplicationContext ctx)
  {
    return args -> {
        // startup code
    };
  }

  @Bean
  public MyNewFilter myFilter ()
  {
    return new MyNewFilter (); //          <----------- THIS IS NEW
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- was correct, the new component is being loaded. The application is misbehaving for unrelated reasons.

I can't delete the post so I'll accept this in 2 days.